# multiple windows services or single windows service with multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

Fairly common scenario, but not able to find anything after googling. any not able to find any related question on SO.

I have multiple service doing different activities. And by multiple services I mean multiple installers. Each installer does its activity in a separate thread started by Timers.

Current we are thinking of having a single service and start all the activities in a separate threads, started by System.Timers.Timer.

Is there any performance implication of having multiple services v/s multiple threads approach. We will be running total 6 services/threads.

Comment: There is.   It's a much bigger PITA installing six services instead of one.  Do you need a timer, or will a simple sleep() loop in each thread do?

Comment: both will do :) i know, i have the same feeling about installing six services..